# Loop through products in collection and find lowest price (excluding $0 prices)

Tags: arrays, shopify, liquid

I have a Shopify site with multiple categories. Some products do not have a price (Shopify interests this as $0). All collections are displayed on the front page. I want to loop through all products in each collection and output the minimum price (excluding $0 values).

The current array I'm using is:

```
{% assign startingFrom = collection.products | sort: 'price' %}
{{ startingFrom[0].price_min | money_without_currency }}
```

Unfortunately, this captures and outputs $0 values.

What is the best way to loop through values that are higher than $0 and output the lowest price?

I have tried to exclucde zero values:

```
{% assign startingFrom = collection.products | sort: 'price' %}
{% if 'price' != 0.00 %}
 {{ startingFrom[0].price_min | money_without_currency }}
{% endif %}
```

This outputs $0.00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% for product in collection.products %}
  {% if forloop.first %}
    {% assign lowest_price = product.price %}
  {% endif %}
  {% assign new_price = product.price %}
  {% if new_price < lowest_price and new_price != 0 %}
    {% assign lowest_price = new_price %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

it is not tested but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on that way unless you have fewer than the pagesize limit of products in your collection.

See the discussion and solution under [Shopify: Getting highest price item from collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351925/shopify-getting-highest-price-item-from-collection/33372020#33372020)