# shopify, forward and back button by filtered product list

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, shopify, liquid

I am trying to make forward and back buttons that will work to be shown on the product page on the collection page. When a filter is selected while on the collection page and then a product is clicked, I want to make buttons that go forward and backward on the products listed according to the filters selected by the user. The buttons I have only go forward and backward on the entire collection page. How can I rewrite the code below to work on the products listed according to the filters?

```
  {%- liquid
    assign previous_product = collection.previous_product
    assign next_product = collection.next_product
       assign backFunc = 
    if previous_product or next_product
    else
        assign collectionList = product.collections[0].handle
        assign previous_product = nil
        assign next_product = nil
        assign last = collections[collectionList].products_count
        for p in collections[collectionList].products
            if p.handle == product.handle
                assign prev = forloop.index | minus: 2
                assign next = forloop.index
                if prev >= 0
                  assign previous_product = collections[collectionList].products[prev].handle
                endif
                if last >= next
                  assign next_product = collections[collectionList].products[next].handle
                endif
                break
            endif
        endfor
    endif
-%} 



{%- if previous_product -%}
            <a class="next-prev-icon prev-icon" href="{{ previous_product }}">
              Prev
            </a>
        {%- endif -%}
        {%- if next_product -%}
            <a class="next-prev-icon next-icon" href="{{ next_product }}">
                Next
            </a>
        {%- endif -%}
```

I searched all over the internet but could not find any results.

Answer (score 0):

Look back at this old post [Shopify: Getting highest price item from collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351925/shopify-getting-highest-price-item-from-collection/33372020#33372020) to get a hint.

Basically you would use a script to detect the filter from the page's document.referrer's search parameters and then re-run that filter via script. Page through the filtered products and when you find your product you rebuild the previous and next buttons client side to point to the correct products.

You can use `window.sessionStorage` to cache the scripted filter product ids in order so that when you load a new page you can check the cache (whose key is the current filter parameters) and if you find your product you can skip the lookup.

If you go the cached route you'll also want to set some sort of staleness criteria.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. But I tried to do it according to the link you gave about how to get only the clicked tags and I couldn't do it. Also, even if I create this filtered products list, how will I integrate it into the liquid code block I gave in the question?

Comment: you don't really integrate it with the liquid. Liquid is a server side technology. The solution I pointed at is a client side technology. Basically you use javascript to replace the event handlers on the buttons produced by your liquid when the product you are looking at was clicked into from a search. You'll know the product came from a search by examining the document.referrer value which is what you'll use to do the client driven query of the list of filtered results.

Comment: I tried to get the parameters, I tried to get the url of the last filtered page, but I could not create an array that lists the filtered products in two different attempts. I am sure that I got the search parameters and the last url properly, I checked with consol.log. I also examined the link you gave, but I couldn't get it done again. I have been dealing with this for 3 weeks. I don't want to tire you out, but if you don't write the whole code, could you please write a code example that will at least be a starting point?

Comment: I am available on Upwork